# how can I reduce database hints in Django ORM?

Tags: django, performance, orm, django-queryset

I have some Models:

`F ---> D ---> C <--- B ---> A`

```
class A:
    -

class B:
    a = ForeignKey
    c = ForeignKey

class C:
    -

class D:
    c = ForeignKey

class F:
    d = ForeignKey
```

and I'm using this query:

```
querset = B.objects.select_related('c').filter(a=a_instance)
```

to show result in template:

```
{% for b in querset %}
    {% for d in b.c.d_set.all %}
        {% for f in d.f_set.all %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

how can I reduce database hints?
is it ok to use Prefetch like this or am I wrong?

```
querset = B.objects.select_related(
        'c'
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('c__d_set__f_set')
    ).filter(
        a=a_instance
    )
```

django = 2.2

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that C doesn't have a field to point to D. So in your template, the line: `{% for d in b.c.d_set.all %}` will have performance issues with the reverse-lookup. I'd suggest something like [this](https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/), which shows you how to cache the related fields from the reverse lookup, to optimize your queries.